# How to create same Command in Java ME

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

i want to use same command for another form in java me. i only see how to create commands but re use it on another form is not. is it possible or should i just copy paste my code to other forms that ill make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lcdui Command](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Command.html) is plain old Java object, its instances can be reused and passed around just like any other Java objects

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;

// usage: CommandPool.cmdHello, CommandPool.cmdBye
public class CommandsPool {
    public static final Command
        cmdHello = new Command("Hello", Command.OK, 0),
        cmdBye = new Command("Bye", Command.EXIT, 0);
}
```

Comment: how about changing display? i have Midlet class and created 3 external class which is commandspool implements commandlistener, 2 classes which extends form, in commandspool commandAction() method, i dont know how to get the instance of the display in Midlet class.

Comment: in the class extending MIDlet, display can be obtained with `Display.getDisplay(this)` and then, you can just pass it around as plain old Java object. Btw given your questions, I would also strongly recommend you to search web for _MIDP getting started_ and _MIDP UI tutorial_